# Check if a date range contains a weekend

Tags: php, date

For a booking, I need to know if a date range is considered as a week-end. Date range considered as weekend are:

- Friday to Monday
- Friday to Sunday
- Saturday to Sunday
- Saturday to Monday

I got 2 variables :

```
$start=YYYY-mm-dd
$end=YYYY-mm-dd
$duration=(integer number of nights)
```

How can I make the test? I don't know much PHP.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have Friday to Monday duplicated, you have to subtract the dates and then with ("d") into a loop you can know what day is it.
[Here you have the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: oops i meant Friday to Sunday, but maybe i can jus test $start and $duration